# How do I do an "and" selector?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I would like to select all elements that have both one class AND another class.  For example, in the following markup, I only want to select elements containing class "foo" and class "bar", but not those that have only one of those classes:

```
<p class="foo">Larry</p>
<p class="bar">Moe</p>
<p class="foo bar">Curly</p>
```

Is there a way in CSS to apply styles only to the paragraph containing "Curly" in the above example?

Comment: @Huangism: The title is perfectly fine as it is, I really don't see why you keep removing a harmless keyword, and especially after a moderator has rolled it back twice. If the title were something like "[CSS] How do I..." then fine, but that's not the case here.

Comment: @BoltClock I was following this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles the title still amkes perfect sense without the tag

Comment: @Huangism "in CSS" is not a "tag" in the title.

Comment: @MattBall Please have a look at the link in my above comment

Comment: @Huangism: I left a comment on that answer.

Comment: I agree the original title was only different in the ordering from the linked question "Select CSS based on multiple classes".  By this argument, "CSS" should have been removed from that one as well.

Comment: @DavidWhiteman honestly `"Select CSS based on multiple classes"` should be `Select element base don multiple classes` I don't think the 'in [tag]' is needed anywhere since the question already tags it. Unless the question title makes no sense without it. In most cases it is not needed

Comment: I'm not sure why my reputation keeps getting dinged for this question. It wasn't easy info to find, at least the way that I thought to look for it.  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp did not have info on how to do this.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the original title and there is no reason to argue over it. As for the downvotes, yeah people can be a bit touchy about frequently-asked duplicates. What I can suggest is tell us within the question itself what research you have done. That gives us a starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate the selector. So you would use `.foo.bar {}`

Comment: Thanks!  It's unfortunate there is no example of this at the following location:  http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @David Whiteman: You can find an example of this usage in the [official W3C spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#class-html). W3Schools isn't always the best resource and it is not affiliated with W3C anyway.

Answer (score 0):

`p.foo.bar { //styles }`

You can concatenate selectors by putting them together.

Of course, you should try to avoid being that specific as it could lead to problems later down the line.

Comment: I don't understand why this is getting downvoted so much when the other two answers are spared, given that all three answers are identical. Even if you want to downvote for your own reasons, at least be fair.

Comment: Because I was first and people hate not being at the top for that sweet, glorious reputation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
p.foo.bar {
    background-color: chucknorris;
}
```

Just append the selectors behind each other, without a space in between.